# How to return 401 error as a json format in Clojure Liberator?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript, compojure, liberator

I'm using liberator for REST service and my content type is json.

When `:authorized?`(or other decisions) fails it returns `text/html` which i don't want.

I need liberator to return json data format for all type of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Handlers](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/handlers.html) can be used to customise what to do in different cases like handle ok, resource is not found or user is not authenticated. For example:

```
(resource
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :authorized? (fn [ctx] ...)
  :handle-unauthorized {:message "You need to be authenticated"}
  :exists? (fn [ctx] ...)
  :handle-not-found {:message "Resource not found"})
```

As in other cases, handler can be a constant value or a function that will produce it.